# How does a SPA work?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, singlepage, single-page-application

I am new to the concept of Single page applications and am trying to understand the server side and client side navigation pattern and request processing lifecycle with SPA. Please excuse me if these are very basic.

If the web app is not cached already on the client side and the user hits a URL, what is the sequence of steps that happen on the server ?

If on the server side SPAs expose only restful data end points, When does partial view get downloaded on the client side ? Does the whole SPA (all the partial views across different views) get downloaded in one shot ? If so, how are the files linked for downloading ?

How do we change layouts across different sections of a SPA ?

When there are more than one page in a "SPA" representing large modules of the web app, how does client side navigation work ?

Comment: Before moving on to the answers, do you have any idea how ASP.NET MVC works, the Controller, the Models, the Views and Partial Views?

Answer (score 4):

Not knowing how much you know about ASP.NET MVC and how the pieces work together, a good startup is the **Plural Sight** course from **[Dan Wahlin](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/Authors/Details?handle=dan-wahlin)** called *Building ASP.NET MVC Apps with EF Code First, HTML5, and jQuery*.

The **course description**: http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/Courses/TableOfContents?courseName=web-development

**Youtube video** showing SPA working and what the whole course project is: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xcp82q6L3lM

It's a **single page application**, that gets data from a database and web services, it uses recent technologies such as EF Code first, Knockout and svg, and makes also use of jQuery templates...

I had the opportunity to see the whole course, and it's lovely... you can get a 10 days [free trial](https://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/Subscribe/Step1?isTrial=True) on Plural Sight.

***P.S.*** I'm a [simple user of Plural Sight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522913/net-video-training-tutorials-when-considering-cost-vs-quality-how-do-learnv/6190210#6190210), I'm not affiliate with them in any other way.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at awesome presentation on how to build SPA on pluralsight by John Papa. Here is the link

http://bit.ly/Papa_SPA

Comment: I have gone through this course as well and it is as you say awesome